# Graphics: Area between curves

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm currently trying to figure out how to create certain graphics containing two curves and shaded the area between them:

[image]

[image]

with `tikz` and `pgftools`. In the first drawing the curves are: f(x)=1/2*x^2-2*x+5 and g(x)=-1/10*x^2+2 and a=1, b=4. In the second one the curves could be f(x)=-1/6*x^2+2, g(x)=1/4*x^2 with x_1=-2.19 and x_2=2.19.

I've read through several threads here but I can't seem to figure out what the code could be so I hope you can help me to deliver my course some nice graphics :)

Comment: A search on this site of "shaded area" produces many hits, such as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129429/how-do-i-shade-an-area-in-pgfplots and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34102/filling-area-between-2-functions-with-shading.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Or this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46187/error-filling-between-curves-in-tikz?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to the site! We've had these questions quite a few times before :) If you could link to those that you have seen, and paste some code that you have tried and where you're stuck, there's a much greater chance that your question will stay open :)

Comment: Since you want to visualize functions and you want to fill between plots, you may want to take a look at the most recent version of `pgfplots`, specifically its `fillbetween` library (compare http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf section "Related libraries >> Fill between")

Answer (score 28):

With recent (v1.10) `fillbetween` pgfplotslibrary and taking a look at pgfplots documentation or suggested answers in comments, it's easy to draw something like

[image]

[image]

with next code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            enlargelimits,
            ytick=\empty,
            xtick={1,4},
            xticklabels={a,b}]
\addplot[name path=F,blue,domain={-.2:5}] {0.5*x^2-2*x+5} node[pos=.8, above]{$f$};

\addplot[name path=G,green,domain={-.2:5}] {-0.1*x^2+2}node[pos=.1, below]{$g$};

\addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50]fill between[of=F and G, soft clip={domain=1:4}]
;
\node[coordinate,pin=30:{$A$}] at (axis cs:3.8,3){};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            enlargelimits,
            ytick=\empty,
            xtick={-2.19,2.19},
            xticklabels={$x_1$,$x_2$}]
\addplot[name path=F,blue,domain={-4:4}] {-(1/6)*x^2+2} node[pos=1, below]{$f$};

\addplot[name path=G,green,domain={-4:4}] {0.25*x^2}node[pos=1, above]{$g$};

\addplot[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=brown!50]fill between[of=F and G, soft clip={domain=-2.19:2.19}]
;
\node[coordinate,pin=60:{$A$}] at (axis cs:1.1,1.6){};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just for typing exercise with PSTricks so I leave the code as is without optimization.

### One

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-eucl}
\def\f{x -.5 sub x 2.5 sub mul 2 div }
\def\g{\f neg }

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](-2,-2)(4.5,4.5)
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \pscustom[fillstyle=vlines,linestyle=none,hatchcolor=lightgray]{\psplot{-1}{3}{\f 2 add}\psplot{3}{-1}{\g 1 sub}}
    \psplot{-1}{3}{\f 2 add}\psplot{-1}{3}{\g 1 sub}
    \psxTick(-1){a}\psxTick(3){b}
    \rput(1,.5){$A$}
    \uput[45](!3 /x ED x \f 2 add){$f$}\uput[-45](!3 /x ED x \g 1 sub){$g$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Two

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-eucl}

\def\f{x -.5 sub x 2.5 sub mul 2 div }
\def\g{\f neg }

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m,saveNodeCoors,hatchsep=2pt](-2,-2)(4.5,4.5)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=vlines,linestyle=none,hatchcolor=lightgray]{\psplot{-1}{3}{\f 3 add}\psplot{3}{-1}{\g .5 sub}}
    % additional procedures:
    \bgroup
        \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
        \pstInterFF{\g .5 sub}{0}{0}{A}
        \pstInterFF{\g .5 sub}{0}{2}{B}
    \egroup
    \pscustom[fillstyle=vlines,linestyle=none,hatchcolor=red]{\psplot{N-A.x}{N-B.x}{\g .5 sub}\psplot{N-B.x}{N-A.x}{0}}
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot{-1}{3}{\f 3 add}\psplot{-1}{3}{\g .5 sub}
    \psxTick(-1){a}\psxTick(3){b}
    \rput(1,1.25){$A$}
    \uput[45](!3 /x ED x \f 3 add){$f$}\uput[-45](!3 /x ED x \g .5 sub){$g$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Three

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-eucl}

\def\f{x -.5 sub x 2.5 sub mul 2 div }
\def\g{\f neg }

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m,saveNodeCoors,hatchsep=2pt](-2,-2)(4.5,4.5)
    % additional procedures:
    \bgroup
        \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none}
        \pstInterFF{\g}{\f 1.2 add}{0}{A}
        \pstInterFF{\g}{\f 1.2 add}{2}{B}
    \egroup
    \pscustom[fillstyle=vlines,linestyle=none,hatchcolor=lightgray]{\psplot{N-A.x}{N-B.x}{\f 1.2 add}\psplot{N-B.x}{N-A.x}{\g}}
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot{-1}{3}{\f 1.2 add}\psplot{-1}{3}{\g}
    \psxTick(-1){a}\psxTick(3){b}
    \rput(!N-A.x N-B.x add 2 div .6){$A$}
    \uput[45](!3 /x ED x \f 1.2 add){$f$}\uput[-45](!3 /x ED x \g){$g$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Latest update

If you want to use infix notation instead of postfix but at the same time you don't want to use `algebraic` option for unknown reason, consider the following. I just used the first case above as an example. The second and third cases are left for your exercises.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-eucl}
\def\f{((x-.5)*(x-2.5)/5)}
\def\g{(-\f)}

\pstVerb{/I2P {exec AlgParser cvx exec} def}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](-2,-2)(4.5,4.5)
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \pscustom[fillstyle=vlines,linestyle=none,hatchcolor=gray]{\psplot{-1}{3}{{(\f+2)} I2P}\psplot{3}{-1}{{(\g-1)} I2P}}
    \psplot{-1}{3}{{(\f+2)} I2P}\psplot{3}{-1}{{(\g-1)} I2P}
    \psxTick(-1){a}\psxTick(3){b}
    \rput*(*1 .5){$A$}
    \uput[45](*3 {\f+2}){$f$}\uput[-45](*3 {\g-1}){$g$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

For the fun with MetaPost, making use of a macro of my own based upon the very handy `buildcycle` macro, in order to create the path bounding the area between the two curves.

Applied here on the OP's second example, which is a bit of particular case, since the two curves intersect. If I have more time this evening, I'll add a more general application.

```
input latexmp;
setupLaTeXMP(options="12pt", textextlabel=enable, mode = rerun);

vardef graph_of_function (suffix f) (expr xmin, xmax, xsep) =
   for x = xmin step xsep until xmax: (x, f(x)) .. endfor (xmax, f(xmax))
enddef ;

vardef vline (suffix f, g) (expr x) = (x, min(f(x), g(x))) -- (x, max(f(x),g(x))) enddef;

vardef area_between_functions (suffix f, g)(expr a, b, xsep) =
   buildcycle(graph_of_function(f, a, b, xsep), vline(f, g, b), 
      reverse graph_of_function(g, a, b, xsep), reverse vline(f, g, a))
enddef;

vardef xaxis (expr xmin, xmax) = (xmin, 0) -- (xmax, 0) enddef ;
vardef yaxis (expr ymin, ymax) = (0, ymin) -- (0, ymax) enddef ;

beginfig(1);
xmin:=-4.5; xmax := 4.5; 
ymin := -1.5; ymax := 5;
u:=1cm;

vardef f(expr x)= (-1/6)*(x**2)+2 enddef;
vardef g(expr x)= 0.25*(x**2) enddef;
path C_f, C_g;
C_f = graph_of_function(f,xmin, xmax, .1);
C_g = graph_of_function(g, xmin, xmax, .1);

a := xpart(C_f intersectionpoint C_g); %a \approx -2.19; 
b := xpart(reverse C_f intersectionpoint reverse C_g); %b \approx 2.19;

fill (area_between_functions(f, g, a, b, 0.1)) scaled u withcolor 0.8white;
draw C_f scaled u;
draw C_g scaled u;
draw ((a, 0)*u -- (a, g(a))*u) dashed evenly;
draw ((b, 0)*u -- (b, g(b))*u) dashed evenly;

drawarrow xaxis(xmin, xmax) scaled u ;
drawarrow yaxis(ymin, ymax) scaled u ;
label.bot("$a \approx" & decimal((round(100*a))/100) & "$", (a*u, 0));
label.bot("$b \approx" & decimal((round(100*b))/100) & "$", (b*u, 0));
label.bot("$x$", (xmax*u, 0));
label.lft("$y$", (0, ymax*u));
label.rt("$f$", (xmax, f(xmax))*u);
label.rt("$g$", (xmax, g(xmax))*u);
endfig;
end.
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\def\f{(x-.5)*(x-2.5)/5+2}
\def\g{-\f-3}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-2,-2)(4.5,4.5)
    \psaxes[ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \pscustom[fillstyle=crosshatch,linestyle=none,hatchcolor=red!50]{
      \psplot{-1}{3}{\f}\psplot{3}{-1}{\g}}
  \psplot{-1}{3}{\f}\psplot{3}{-1}{\g}
  \psxTick(-1){a}\psxTick(3){b}
  \rput*(1,.5){$A$}
  \uput[45](*3 {\f}){$f$}\uput[-45](*3 {\g}){$g$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]