# Shading a region between two polar curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis, polarplot

I'm using Tikz and have two polar curves `r=1.5+cos(t)` and `r=1.5`. I would like to fill (shade) the area between curves (shown by an arrow on the picture). How can I do this? Maybe using `\clip` or something?

[image]

I tried `\tikzfillbetween` but it behaves weirdly in polar coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, intersections, fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid = both]
    % Outer curve
    \addplot [data cs=polar, domain=0:360, samples=180, black,
        line width=1pt, smooth](x, {1.5+cos(x)});
    % Inner curve
    \addplot [data cs=polar, domain=0:360, samples=180, green,
        line width=1pt, smooth](x, 1.5);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thanks for the advise I've edited my question.

Comment: See: [Graphics: Area between curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165275/124842). I think its a duplicat... have a look...

Comment: In the question that you linked the curves are not polar. And it does not work here. I would like an approach suitable for polar curves.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 13):

You could use `intersection segments`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}% <- added!!
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}% <- changed
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid = both,
    set layers% <- added
]
    % Outer curve
    \addplot [data cs=polar, domain=0:360, samples=180, black,
        line width=1pt, smooth,
        name path=outer
        ](x, {1.5+cos(x)});
    % Inner curve
    \addplot [data cs=polar, domain=0:360, samples=180, green,
        line width=1pt, smooth,
        name path=inner
        ](x, 1.5);
    % Filling
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{axis background}
      \fill [orange!30,
          intersection segments={
            of=inner and outer,
            sequence={L0--L1--R1[reverse]--R0[reverse]}
          }];
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Example showing the segments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}% <- added!!
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}% <- changed
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid = both,
    set layers% <- added
]
    % Outer curve
    \addplot [data cs=polar, domain=0:360, samples=180, black,
        line width=1pt, smooth,
        name path=outer
        ](x, {1.5+cos(x)});
    % Inner curve
    \addplot [data cs=polar, domain=0:360, samples=180, green,
        line width=1pt, smooth,
        name path=inner
        ](x, 1.5);
    % Filling
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{axis background}
        \fill [orange!30,
            intersection segments={
              of=inner and outer,
              sequence={L0--L1--R1[reverse]--R0[reverse]}
            }];
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{axis}
% Showing the segments
\begin{scope}[line width=2pt,->,font=\bfseries]
    \foreach[count=\i from 0] \c in {green,orange,purple}{
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw [\c,
            intersection segments={of=inner and outer,sequence={L\i}}]node[left]{L\i};}
        \temp}
     \foreach[count=\i from 0] \c in {blue,gray,yellow}{
         \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw [\c,
            intersection segments={of=inner and outer,sequence={R\i}}]node[right]{R\i};}
         \temp}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution, maybe not the optimal one, but it allows to generalize. In `(axis cs: {(1.5)*cos(\x)}, {(1.5)*sin(\x)})` in the frame inside `scope` one can substitude any polar equation in the form `r(\x)` instead of (both) `1.5`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, intersections, fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid = both]
    % Outer curve
    \addplot [data cs=polar, domain=0:360, samples=180, black,
        line width=1pt, smooth](x, {1.5+cos(x)});
    % Inner curve
    \addplot [data cs=polar, domain=0:360, samples=180, green,
        line width=1pt, smooth](x, 1.5);
    % Shading        
    \begin{scope}
        % Frame (inversed)
        \path[clip] plot[domain=0:360, samples=180] 
            (axis cs: {(1.5)*cos(\x)}, {(1.5)*sin(\x)}) 
            -- (current page.north east) -- (current page.south east) 
            -- (current page.south west) -- (current page.north west) 
            -- (current page.north east);
        % framed plot
        \addplot [data cs=polar, domain=0:360, samples=180, draw=none,
            fill = yellow!40!white, fill opacity = 0.5,
            line width=1pt, smooth](x, {1.5+cos(x)});
    \end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A way of doing it with MetaPost, for whom it may interest.

**Edit**  My first attempt made use of the otherwise very handy `buildcycle` macro, but I've just realized that filling the cardioid and then unfilling the circle is much simpler in this particular case.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85, luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef plrfcn(expr tmin, tmax, tstep)(text r_t) =
    save t; t := tmin;
    (r_t)*dir t forever: hide(t := t + tstep) exitunless t <= tmax; 
        .. (r_t)*dir t 
    endfor
    if t-tstep < tmax: hide(t := tmax) .. (r_t)*dir t fi    
enddef;
u = cm; xmin = -2; xmax = 3; ymax = -ymin = 2;
beginfig(1);
    % grid
    for x = xmin upto xmax:
        draw u*(x, ymin) -- u*(x, ymax) withcolor .8white;
        if x>xmin: label.bot(TEX("$" & decimal x & "$"), u*(x, ymin)) fi;
    endfor;
    for y = ymin upto ymax:
        draw u*(xmin, y) -- u*(xmax, y) withcolor .8white;
        label.lft(TEX("$" & decimal y & "$"), u*(xmin, y));
    endfor; 
    % polar curves and filled area
    path cardio, circle; 
    circle = (plrfcn(0, 359, 1)(1.5) .. cycle) scaled u;
    cardio = (plrfcn(0, 359, 1)(1.5 + cosd t) .. cycle) scaled u;
    fill cardio withcolor .25[white, yellow]; unfill circle;
    draw cardio; draw circle withcolor green;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An emergency-purpose-only solution with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic,polarplot,plotpoints=100](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=polar,tickcolor=gray!25,ylabelFactor=^\circ](3,0)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow!25]
    {
        \psplot{PiDiv2}{PiDiv2 neg}{1.5}
        \psplot{PiDiv2 neg}{PiDiv2}{1.5+cos(x)}     
    }   
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{0}{TwoPi}{1.5}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi}{1.5+cos(x)}        
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]